# Zero padding multiple values in Python

Tags: python, numpy

In another SO, this is a solution for adding a single zero between values in a `numpy.array`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(1, 7)                 # array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
np.insert(arr, slice(1, None, 2), 0)  # array([1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6])
```

How would I add more zeros between each value in original array? For example, 5 zeros:

```
np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6])
```

Comment: I am curious as to what you are trying to solve with this.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a 2dim array, and flatten it:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(1,7)
num_zeros = 5
z = np.zeros((a.size, num_zeros))

np.append(a[:,np.newaxis], z, axis=1)
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 6.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

np.append(a[:,np.newaxis], z, axis=1).flatten()
array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  4.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  6.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])

np.append(a[:,np.newaxis], z, axis=1).flatten()[:-num_zeros]
array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  4.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  6.])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way, using insert:

```
In [31]: arr
Out[31]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

In [32]: nz = 5

In [33]: pos = np.repeat(range(1,len(arr)), nz)

In [34]: pos
Out[34]: 
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5,
   5, 5])

In [35]: np.insert(arr, pos, 0)
Out[35]: 
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6])
```

Here's another way.  This method requires no temporary arrays, so it should be much more efficient. The padded array `b` is preallocated using `np.zeros`, and then the values from `arr` are copied into `b` with a sliced assignment:

```
In [45]: b = np.zeros(1 + (nz+1)*(arr.size-1), dtype=arr.dtype)

In [46]: b.size
Out[46]: 31

In [47]: b[::nz+1] = arr

In [48]: b
Out[48]: 
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be pure NumPy, you could do something like this:

```
import numpy

def pad(it, zero_count):
    it = iter(it)
    yield next(it)
    while True:
        element = next(it)
        for n in xrange(zero_count):
            yield 0
        yield element

arr = numpy.fromiter(pad(xrange(1, 7), 5), int, -1)
```

or if you want to optimize allocation a bit:

```
values = xrange(1, 7)
zero_count = 5
total_length = len(values) + max(0, len(values)-1) * zero_count
arr = numpy.fromiter(pad(values, zero_count), int, total_length)
```